# how to add records while dataset records empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

- I'm inserting records in gridview, but its showing no record.
- I want to show footer as well as insert button to insert first
  record.
- How to add record while no records found

  ```
  private void fillgrid()
  {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_FunctionalAccess", connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GrdvDetail.DataSource = ds;
        GrdvDetail.DataBind();
  }
  ```

how to show insert button while no records are there.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdvDetail" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found" SkinID="gridviewSkin" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
    runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanged="GrdvDetail_PageIndexChanged"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GrdvDetail_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdvDetail_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowEditing="GrdvDetail_RowEditing"
    OnRowUpdated="GrdvDetail_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="GrdvDetail_RowUpdating"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GrdvDetail_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowFooter="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LkB1" runat="server" CommandName="Select">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="IDvalue" Value='<%#Eval("ID")%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("UserName")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqName" ValidationGroup="insertValdate" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="txtName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter UserName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PageName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%-- <asp:HiddenField ID="HFPage" Value='<%#Eval("PageName")%>' runat="server" />--%>
                <%#Eval("PageName")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPageName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PageName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPageName1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ReadPermission">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("ReadPermission")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRead" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ReadPermission")) %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="FchkRead" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WritePermission">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("WritePermission")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWrite" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("WritePermission")) %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="FchkWrite" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```